# Как ПРОСТО загружать файл на php, без его сохранения?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Подключил библиотеку PHPExcel, все там подключил, сделал настройку файлов, все такое, но нужно, чтобы сгенерированный файл просто качался, а не создавался в папке.. Как это сделать?
Долго гуглил, но так и ничего и не нашел.

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');ob_start();$objWriter->save('php://output');$excelOutput = ob_get_clean();
```

^ не помог :(

Comment: PHPExcel умер три года назад, немного странно его использовать в 2020-м

Comment: «не помог» — почему?

Comment: @andreymal, ну не сработало

Comment: Что значит «не сработало»? Что произошло вместо срабатывания?

Comment: Ну вот ничего не произошло ))

Comment: И даже никаких ошибок не напечатало?

Comment: да вообще ничего : /

Comment: мне нужно foreachем достать найденого запросом юзера и скачать его инфу в формате екзеля

Comment: @andreymal , нужен код?

Comment: вы с этим `$excelOutput` что-то делаете потом, или что? на кой вы тут буферизацию используете, если хотите отдать файл пользователю все равно?

Comment: @teran , это просто код который мне могут кинуть. просто сказал сразу, что не помогло

Comment: @teran , может быть даже сама загрузка через какую-то команду этой библиотеки не нужны? Мне нужно просто чтобы по событию на кнопку, циклом обходился каждый юзер сохранялся его excel, скачивал его и переходил к другому, массив из запроса. Как так сделать фор ичем?

Comment: веб-сервер не может отправить больше одного файла за раз. поэтому даже не говоря обо всех других проблемах - уж во всяком случае никаких циклов, разумеется.

Comment: Вообще, не нужно ставить себе искусственных ограничений, если у тебя вообще ничего не получается. сделай с сохранением сначала, а потом уже делай без.

Comment: @Ипатьев, Да, уже сделал с сохранением. Блин, вообще никак нельзя отправлять больше одного файла?? Можно например в папку это все помещать?

Comment: Скажи, ты интернетом когда-нибудь вообще пользовался в своей жизни? Ну просто как пользователь? Скачивал когда-нибудь что-ниубудь с сайта? Тебе сайт когда-нибудь папку предлагал скачать?

Comment: Можно файлы в зип архив положить

Comment: @Ипатьев, ну я и про это говорил

Answer (score 0):

```
$excel = new PHPExcel();

// вывод заголовков для скачивания
header('Content-Type:xlsx:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="Название файла.xlsx"');

// вывод данных для скачивания
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Excel2007');
@$objWriter->save('php://output');
```